# laravel ORM models are showing the same values in all requests

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a problem with basic laravel ORM models. I am calling `image` model to get image's filename for every `product` (`product` model has `image_id` value) so I am fetching `products` from the database and using `foreach` loop to loop all images and add filename to each `product`:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    $pimg = image::find($product->image_id)->first()->filename;
    $product->imagefilename = $pimg;
}
```

The problem is that all products in result are showing the same filename in `imagefilename` (JSON encoded response):

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "dell-v3557",
        "description": "this is dell v3557 ,this is description",
        "short_description": "short description of dell v3557",
        "category_id": 1,
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "image_id": 1,
        "store_id": 1,
        "price": 2100,
        "discount_price": 1800,
        "count": 5,
        "countries": "all",
        "created_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "imagefilename": "dell-v3557.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "gr5-2017",
        "description": "this is gr5 2017 , lorem ipsum dolor , this is description",
        "short_description": "short description of gr5",
        "category_id": 1,
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "image_id": 2,
        "store_id": 1,
        "price": 700,
        "discount_price": 550,
        "count": 2,
        "countries": "all",
        "created_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "imagefilename": "dell-v3557.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "iphone 11 pro",
        "description": "this is iphone 11 pro , lorem ipsum dolor , this is description",
        "short_description": "short description of iphone 11 pro",
        "category_id": 1,
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "image_id": 4,
        "store_id": 1,
        "price": 1400,
        "discount_price": null,
        "count": 8,
        "countries": "all",
        "created_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "imagefilename": "dell-v3557.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "macbook pro",
        "description": "this is macbook pro , lorem ipsum dolor , this is description",
        "short_description": "short description of macbook pro",
        "category_id": 1,
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "image_id": 5,
        "store_id": 1,
        "price": 1850,
        "discount_price": 1700,
        "count": 13,
        "countries": "all",
        "created_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-28T11:07:10.000000Z",
        "imagefilename": "dell-v3557.png"
    }
]
```

I also tried using `[ $img = new image; ]` in every loop in case it was the problem with using the same model many times, but no luck, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but the problem is not `find`, it is that you have done `find(...)->first()`, so it get's the image but you then do `first` so you get again the first `Images` model...

Your solution should be:

```php
$pimg = image::find($product->image_id)->filename;
```

This is the Laravel way, not yours.

---

`find($id)` is an *alias* of `where(PRIMARY_MODEL_KEY_COLUMN, $id)->first()`...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, the problem was in `::find()` method. I used `::where` instead:

```
$pimg = image::where("id",$product->image_id)->first()->filename;
```

Now it's getting images' filenames properly without repeating.